# Get value of Select box within some divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

By `document.getElementByTagName[select][1].value;` I can get my value, what if I want to get value using `div`, like first `select` box value within a `div`

```
<select>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select>

<div id="firstdiv">
    <select>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
    </select>

    <select>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this...

```
//get the div
var theDiv = document.getElementById("firstdiv");
//get the first select option from thediv
var theSelect = theDiv.getElementsByTagName("select")[0].value;

console.log("theVal",theSelect)
```

Since you have also tagged this as a jQuery question as well ill add this

```
var theSelect = $("#firstdiv select :first").val(); 
console.log("theVal",theSelect)
```

Comment: thank you , but this theDiv.getElementsByTagName("select")[0].value; doesn't work for me ,i don't know why, everything seems all right

Comment: @Sooraz here is fiddler version working with the code you have provided  http://jsfiddle.net/screepts/y0khgv8h/2/